# how to configure dynamic Virtual host with dynamic SSL configuration in nginx?

Tags: dynamic, nginx, virtualhost

Is it possible to configure dynamic SSL certificate path in nginx same as like dynamic virtual host.

ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key are not accepting the variables in nginx.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it's not possible because nginx needs to load the whole SSL server configuration at start time.

Source: https://t37.net/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-virtual-hosting-with-nginx.html

Answer (score 3):

Since Nginx version **1.15.9** variables are supported in "ssl_certificate" and "ssl_certificate_key" directives.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate

Answer (score 1):

You can load them dynamically by using lua.
You need to figure out how you want to map and fetch them though.

Here is an example of loading them from a database:
https://github.com/Vestorly/nginx-dynamic-ssl/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can refer shared video to make it happen.
Here you can pass dynamic variable with ssl param in nginx.conf.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeLE988jmlo

Variable is $ssl_server_name.
Store your SSL certificate with name of domain name.
ex. example.com.cert